# How to fix Stats Model (model is missing required outcome variables)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, statsmodels

I just started machine learning in python and I was studying about Multiple Linear Regression. Where I learn about Dummy Variable trap and which can be solve by backward elimination but while applying backward elimination i am getting this error. (PatsyError: model is missing required outcome variables)

These are my imported files

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
```

These are first 5 rows of my data set:

```
        gender    age    exercise    hours     grade
0       female    17        3        10        82.4
1       male      18        4        4         78.2
2       male      18        5        9         79.3
3       female    14        2        7         83.2
4       female    18        4        15        87.4


real_x = data_frame.iloc[:,:4].values
real_y = data_frame.iloc[:,4:].values

label_encoder_obj = LabelEncoder()
real_x[:,0] = label_encoder_obj.fit_transform(real_x[:,0])
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[2])
real_x = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(real_x).toarray()

real_x = real_x[:,1:]
training_x,test_x,training_y,test_y=
train_test_split(real_x,real_y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

multiple_linear_regression = LinearRegression()
multiple_linear_regression.fit(training_x,training_y)
predection_y = multiple_linear_regression.predict(test_x)


real_x=np.append(arr=np.ones((real_x.shape[0],1)).astype(int),
values=real_x,axis=1)

x_optimization = real_x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
```

In the bellow line I am getting error.

```
regresion_ordinary_least_squar = sm.ols(real_y,data=x_optimization).fit();
```

# if missing == 'raise' there's not missing_mask

```
PatsyError: model is missing required outcome variables
```

And I have seen some online example in which some of code

```
sm.OLS()
```

is used instead of

```
sm.ols()
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Looking at your code it appears that the api for the above is
```smf.ols('Lottery ~ Literacy + np.log(Pop1831)', data=dat).fit()``` (taken from the https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html document) so it appears that you need to pass in a formula.

Comment: and how to pass formula? and what it,s means? Can you please tell what is happening under the hood. @Chinny84

Comment: You can type this in the command line/cell block etc `sm.ols?` this will show you how to use the function (also the link I provided should give clarity). Have you used R before? you  have to give a formula of `<outcome> ~ independent variables list` as a formula.

Comment: Yes I have learn the Basics of R before. I will search about formula, Thanks a lot really appreciate your help. @Chinny84

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer up front: You are mixing up two different versions of statsmodels's ols implementation and have given the model you picked the wrong inputs.

Long answer:
Statsmodel includes two versions of an ordinary least squares model.

The accepted import setups that I've seen are:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

then it's a choice:

```
sm.OLS()
smf.ols()
```

and they behave different.

sm.OLS takes separate X and y dataframes (or exog and endog).  sm.OLS also does NOT add a constant to the model. You need to add that first. Also note that the statsmodel version switches the order to enter the variables - Y then X. Backwards from the way the sklearn models enter their data.

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
result.summary()
```

This also works:

```
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
model.summary()
```

The `.summary()` presents an output of the model's scores, coefficients and p-values.

smf.ols takes a patsy phrase and a dataframe that includes both the response or target variable and all the features.  The patsy phrase allows you to tell the model which columns to use in creating it's ols model for the response variable. A patsy phrase is a string which will look like `'y ~ X1 + X2 + X3'`.  Further, the smf.ols version adds an intercept by default.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':x, 'X2':x2, 'X3':x3, 'y':Y})
model = smf.ols('y ~ X1 + X2 + X3', df).fit()
```

alternately,

```
phrase = 'y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4'
model = smf.ols(phase,df).fit()
```

then do:

```
model.summary2()
```

to retrieve a nicely formatted summary of the scores, coefficients and p-values, much like the `sm.OLS` summary, but slightly different.

If you structure your inputs correctly for the statsmodel version you choose, that error should go away.

Personally, I favor the formula model. But it does get awkward when you split up your dataframe into X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test.

When I'm doing that, I set up my model like:

```
frames =[y_train, X_train]
df_train = pd.concat(frames, axis=1).reindex(y_train.index)

model = smf.ols(formula, df_train).fit()
```

I note that you are also using sklearn's LinearRegression. By default, it also includes the intercept. All three should give similar answers on the same data, if you add the constant to the sm.OLS model.
read a write up about that on kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/agailloty/linear-regression-with-sklearn-and-statsmodel).

Answer (score 1):

You should use

> import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm;

instead of

> import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

and use

> regresion_ordinary_least_squar = sm.OLS(endog = real_y, exog = x_optimization).fit()

instead of

> regresion_ordinary_least_squar = sm.ols(real_y,data=x_optimization).fit();